# Laravel -Strange Behaivor. Controller data and Blade data

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I am returning a value from a variable in my controller but it yields different results when I dd($roles) in my blade view.

```
public function index()
{
    $users = $this->user->getAll(); //DBUserRepository
    $roles = $this->user->getRoles($users)
    return $roles;
}
```

Yields correct results

```
{
id: "1",
username: "Muzikman",
email: "matt.paolini@gmail.com",
password: "$2y$10$Sp7k9Fs0DwFSYHTpWrTWquFmXJpkiKfRIHsjYtdEXTvbdOJwv9AtG",
password_confirmation: "",
confirmation_code: "91f0583ed76c95ebf378648d65d0eac7",
remember_token: "bGmdTchXtilBj41FIazkFS3PDZzr1tVKmTFnMkeeSoD7wpW6hoQ07A42plle",
confirmed: "1",
created_at: "2014-10-19 12:17:55",
updated_at: "2014-10-20 15:07:01",
roles: [
     {
     id: "12",
     name: "Members",
     created_at: "2014-10-24 20:45:26",
     updated_at: "2014-10-24 20:45:26",
     }
     ]
```

However, when return $roles from controller to blade it yields different results.

```
public function index() { $users = $this->user->getAll(); $roles = $this->user->getRoles($users);
return View::view('admin.index', compact('users'))->withRoles($roles); }
```

Blade var dump {{ dd($roles) }} returns

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
object(User)[254]
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'table' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Muzikman' (length=8)
      'email' => string 'matt.paolini@gmail.com' (length=22)
      'password' => string '$2y$10$Sp7k9Fs0DwFSYHTpWrTWquFmXJpkiKfRIHsjYtdEXTvbdOJwv9AtG'       
      'password_confirmation' => string '' (length=0)
      'confirmation_code' => string '91f0583ed76c95ebf378648d65d0eac7' (length=32)
      'remember_token' => string 'bGmdTchXtilBj41FIazkFS3PDZzr1tVKmTFnMkeeSoD7wpW6hoQ07A42plle' (
      'confirmed' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_at' => string '2014-10-19 12:17:55' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-10-20 15:07:01' (length=19)
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Muzikman' (length=8)
      'email' => string 'matt.paolini@gmail.com' (length=22)
      'password' => string '$2y$10$Sp7k9Fs0DwFSYHTpWrTWquFmXJpkiKfRIHsjYtdEXTvbdOJwv9AtG' 
      'password_confirmation' => string '' (length=0)
      'confirmation_code' => string '91f0583ed76c95ebf378648d65d0eac7' (length=32)
      'remember_token' => string 'bGmdTchXtilBj41FIazkFS3PDZzr1tVKmTFnMkeeSoD7wpW6hoQ07A42plle' (length=60)
      'confirmed' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_at' => string '2014-10-19 12:17:55' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-10-20 15:07:01' (length=19)
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=1)
```

Can someone explain what is going on here? Sending the same data object to blade from the controller with different array contents.

Here is the code from my interface:

```
public function getRoles($users)
 {

   foreach($users as $user){
       $roles[] = \User::with('roles')->find($user->id);
   }

    return $roles;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dd($roles)` will spit out the object itself, as see in the second set of output.

`{{ $roles }}` is going to spit out the object having been run through its `toJson()` function, resulting in your first set of output.

Answer (score 0):

in this code

```
public function index()
{
    $users = $this->user->getAll(); //DBUserRepository
    $roles = $this->user->getRoles($users)
    return $roles;
}
```

you did not dump it, you return the $roles, i think, when you return something and the content is "JSONable", laravel will set the appropriate header and convert the content to JSON. (found in Illuminate\Http\Response)

while the other one

```
{{ dd($roles) }}
```

it is same with

```
<?php var_dump($roles); ?>
```

which in PHP says that the said function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value.

Answer (score 0):

I am just curious. If you are just getting 'roles' column by ::with('roles') function. Why did other info come up in your dd() function result?